# How to get the return status in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am calling the executable from python script using sub process call. these are the following code I have used:

```
try:
    p = subprocess.Popen([abc.exe], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

except Exception as e:
    print str(e)
```

from abc.exe, I have return 1 in failure case and return 0 for success case. But I don't know how to check the return value in python script.

thanks,

Comment: There are two problems with this code:
1. You forgot quotes around 'abc.exe', which will cause a NameError to be raised for a non-existent variable 'abc'
2. You're catching Exception, which will catch the NameError.  You should only catch OSError.

Answer (score 3):

[`Popen.returncode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode) contains the return code when the process has terminated. You can ensure that using [`Popen.wait`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait).

Answer (score 1):

You've saved as `p` the output from `.communicate()`, not `Popen` object.  Perhaps try:

```
try:
    p = subprocess.Popen(['abc.exe'], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

except OSError as e:
    print str(e)

stdoutdata, stderrdata = p.communicate()
retcode = p.returncode
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use `subprocess.check_output()` since you mention Python 2.7. This runs the command with the same arguments as `Popen`. The output of the command is returned as a string. If the command returns a non-zero value, a `subprocess.CalledProcessError` exception is raised.

So I think you can rework your code to something like this:

```
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(['abc.exe'], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as ex:
    # an error occurred
    retcode = ex.returncode
    output = ex.output
else:
    # no error occurred
    process(output)
```

Note that you can't use the `stdout` argument in `check_output` since it is used internally. Here are the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).